# How to play a sound on a certain condition?

Tags: javascript, html5-audio

I am making a web server to output the pressure values of a graph on a website. If the pressure is too low/high, I want to play a sound warning the user. I cannot seem to find the way to do this, as I have a unique problem: I have to have `<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1" />` in my html code. This of course refreshes the page every second, so even if I have a button for the user to click the first time the pressure is too low, the page is instantly reloaded and I get a "Uncaught (in promise) DOMException" in the console next time the audio is supposed to play. Here is the code I have so far, shortened to show the necessary parts:

HTML:

```
<audio id="alert_sound" controls>
  <source src="chime.mp3" type="audio/mp3">
  <source src="chime.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
</audio>
```

Javascript:

```
var arduino = [2.11,2.07,2.06,08,1.82,2.00,2.13,1.85,2.15,1.73]
var sound = document.getElementById("alert_sound");
if (Math.min(...arduino) < 5) {
    const playPromise = sound.play();
    if (playPromise !== null) {
        playPromise.catch(() => { sound.play(); })
    };
```

I found the final 4 lines of the js as an answer somewhere else that I thought would work, but it turned out fruitless too.

Comment: How and where are you getting the pressure values from? I suggest you forget about the http-equiv method of refreshing the webpage, and instead use an ajax call to update the content.

Comment: @KostasX the first line of the javascript file is updated (overwritten) using python, getting the values from an Arduino serial monitor. As I know nothing about ajax, would the ajax call be written in the javascript?

Comment: Yes, you need to do an ajax call, for example using the JS fetch() API to some kind of source that gets updated. You can either fetch the page that gets updated with Python or provide a JSON endpoint (again in Python) that will provide the pressure data in JSON format. An easy way to do the latter in py is using a framework like Flask.

Comment: You can even use the jQuery (a popular JS library) load() method to load page data. Reference: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/jquery-load-with-examples/

Comment: @warren Did you find your answer yet?

Comment: @UtkarshPramodGupta Not entirely, I am running into so many issues with CORS policy in chrome etc that I will probably not waste any more time on this. Thank y'all for your time though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It's because of Chrome's new Audio policy.

As you can see in the example below, the audio won't really start to play until you click that non-sensical *click me* button. Google Chrome's new Audio Play policy says, the user first has to interact with the document for audios to get played. Read more about it [here](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/autoplay-policy-changes).

```js
var sound = document.getElementById("sound");

setInterval(() => sound.play(), 3000)
```

```html
<audio id="sound" controls>
   <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/horse.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
</audio>    

<button>click me</button>
```